# my cat won't wean her kittens

Tags: cats, feeding

I am perplexed. I have a first-time mother cat.she won't wean her kittens. I have gone from soft to hard food with the kittens. but yet mother still nurses. kittens are 12 weeks old, should mother not have stopped nursing?